# applying your own policy in GPMC console

Tags: active-directory

In GMPC console, i set a policy on my OU for overriding the default domain policy, then with group policy modeling i can see that my own policy applied to the OU, but in general the applied policy is the default domain policy, also I know the no override is'nt active on the upper OU. is there any other config that i must do?
my purpose is removing password complexity on my own OU without any change in default domain policy.
please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one password policy per domain - in order to have more granular control, you need to implement something called PSO's or Password Setting Objects. These are applied at a group level (security groups, users etc.). Create a security group for the contents of that User OU and apply it to that group. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(v=ws.10).aspx